# How to display multiple point clouds in rapid succession in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, video, playback

This is my first Stack Overflow post so bear with me.
I have several point clouds, that were captured at 60 frames per second (one cloud was generated every 1/60th of a second) and I want to play them back as volumetric video inside of Unity. I cannot come up with the best way to do this. I have figured out how to bring the clouds into Unity using PCX. I cannot figure out how to make the point clouds play back. I know that I will have to write some C# but I'm not even sure how to begin the problem. If anyone could advise I would appreciate it. The point cloud data exists as .PLY's but I could convert them if it would make the process easier. but the end goal is volumetric play back.

I haven't tried much so far because I'm not even exactly sure the best method of approach for the problem.